# Why does abs(complex<int>) always return zero?

Tags: c++, math, stl, std, complex-numbers

The following code with VS2010 prints `0`, contrary to my expectations:

```
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    complex<int> z(20, 200);
    cout << abs<int>(z) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It works fine when the type is `double`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to the C++ ISO spec, §26.2/2:

> The effect of instantiating the template `complex` for any type other than `float`, `double` or `long double` is unspecified.

In other words, the compiler can do whatever it wants to when you instantiate `complex<int>`.  The fact that you're getting 0 here is perfectly well-defined behavior from a language perspective.

For a comparison - on [ideone's version of gcc](http://ideone.com/5c0B4), this code doesn't even compile.  That's another perfectly valid option.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Huh, I'm not even allowed to use my own real number type? That's disappointing.

Comment: @PaulManta- Yeah, I guess not.  I have no idea why this is.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Returning 0, 200 or 42 when behavior is unspecified might be indeed according to a standard, but surely it is quite a pitfall for the casual programmer like me.

Comment: @Artium: There are only two pitfalls: one, you did not properly read the specification, and two, the compiler did not produce an error, which it should have done.

Comment: @DeadMG- Unfortunately, the spec doesn't require the compiler to produce any diagnostics: "The implementation is not required to document which behavior occurs" (&sect;1.3/13)

Comment: @templatetypedef: Sure, but that does not mean that there is no burden for them to produce an error.

Comment: Technically, that is exactly what *unspecified behavior* means -- there is no burden on them to do anything at all, up to and including accidentally doing exactly what you expected, as long as its consistent about it.

Comment: Yuck, we just had a bug at work related to this...

Answer (score 6):

On MinGW 4.6.2 it prints `200`.

However, in the C++ ISO standard section 26.2.2:

> The effect of instantiating the template `complex` for any type other than `float`, `double` or `long double` is unspecified.

So your build environment is exhibiting undefined behavior for `complex<int>`, which is not against the standard.

As `templatetypedef` pointed out, [ideone's C99 compiler](http://ideone.com/5c0B4) (GCC 4.3.4) refuses to compile it altogether.

Comment: @DeadMG - The version used in `templatetypedef`'s example is 4.3.4, for C99. Your link uses C++0x, which is version 4.5.1, see [this page](http://ideone.com/samples#sample_lang_44)