# Why does C++ mandate that complex only be instantiated for float, double, or long double?

Tags: c++, math, language-design, complex-numbers

According to the C++ ISO spec, §26.2/2:

> The effect of instantiating the template `complex` for any type other than `float`, `double` or `long double` is unspecified.

Why would the standard authors explicitly add this restriction?  This makes it unspecified, for example, what happens if you make `complex<int>` or a `complex<MyCustomFixedPointType>` and seems like an artificial restriction.

Is there a reason for this limitation?  Is there a workaround if you want to instantiate `complex` with your own custom type?

I'm primarily asking this question because of [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11108587/501557), in which the OP was confused as to why `abs` was giving bizarre outputs for `complex<int>`.  That said, this still doesn't quite make sense given that we also might want to make `complex` numbers out of fixed-points types, higher-precision real numbers, etc.

Comment: I had to laugh after seeing your previous answer, but it really is a good question.

Comment: @chris- I felt bad giving that answer without being able to give a high-level reason for it.  I'm usually good at saying "this is a bizarre edge case of C++ for reasons X, Y, and Z," but this time I have no idea what's up.

Comment: "Standardizing complex<integral> has been discussed on the committee off and on for over a decade and there exists significant resistance from at least one vendor for supporting it." http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-dev/2012-March/020398.html

Comment: I can't speak for the designers, but as a practical matter lots of the math you need to implement uses methods that really make sense only for floating point types - square roots, atan2s, etc.

Comment: Just take a look at the implementation in the `complex` header file and see how much transcendentals are used inside the template. Are they all available for integers or fixed-point numbers, because computing even such a simple thing as the argument requires `atan2()`.

Comment: @HristoIliev- The fact that it's *difficult* to implement `complex` for arbitrary types doesn't necessarily mean that it should be *impossible* to do so.  The C++ spec could have defined a new set of traits (similar to container requirements or allocator requirements) saying "if you can implement the following, then you can be stored in a `complex`."

Comment: "Unspecifed" is not the same as "Undefined" or "ill formed."  Unspecified, in standardese, means "This is potentially legal, but the Standard doesn't require it, and you need to check your compiler docs to see if it's allowed in your actual implementation."

Comment: To be fair, leaving behavior unspecified is exactly the opposite of a limitation, as far as compiler developers are concerned.

Comment: Yes, the committee just weasels out of having to define what, precisely, a `T` needs to support for `complex<T>` to be allowed. If you overload the transcendentals and `abs()` (finally allowed in C++11 (C++98 allowed full specialisations, but no overloads of names in the `std` namespace)) for your infinite-precision or fixed-point arithmetic type, it will just work. I would consider something like `__isinf` being used in the implenentation w/o a way to specialise for your type a quality-of-implementation bug. Even then, you could still specialize the affected methods for your type explicitly.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can't properly implement many of the `std::complex` operations on integers. E.g.,

```
template <class T>
T abs(const complex<T> &z);
```

for a `complex<long>` cannot have `T = long` return value when complex numbers are represented as (real,imag) pairs, since it returns the value of `sqrt(pow(z.real(), 2) + pow(z.imag(), 2))`. Only a few of the operations would make sense.

Even worse, the [`polar`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/polar) named constructor cannot be made reliable without breaking the default constructor and vice versa. The standard would have to specify that "complex integers" are [Gaussian integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer) for them to be of any use, and that one of the constructors is severely broken.

Finally, how would you like your "complex integer division" served, and would you like a "complex remainder" with that? :)

Summarizing, I think it would be more sensible to specify a separate `gaussian_int<T>` type with just a few operations than graft support for integral `T` onto `std::complex`.

Comment: Funny how we chose the exact same function to illustrate. :)

Comment: Thanks for introducing a solid mathematical reason for the decision.  I think this provides an elegant theoretical reason for the decision.  I had not previously heard of the Gaussian integers, so thanks for bringing them up!

Comment: @templatetypedef: Thank you and +1 for the question. I'd never considered what would happen when `complex` was templated on integral types. [I'm not a mathematician, though, and if anyone can prove me wrong on this, please do.]

Comment: I know it was only meant rhetorically, but the Gaussian integers are a Euclidean domain (and even norm-Euclidean), and so division with remainder behaves essentially the same way as it it does with the ordinary integers; you just have a few more choices of rounding modes.

Answer (score 13):

Probably for compatibility with the helper functions. For example:

```
template<class T> T abs (const complex<T>& x);
```

If `T == int`, `abs` would return `int`, which would mean a massive loss in precision.

Comment: We already accept massive loss of precision in integer division. `5/3 = 1`. I think we could similarly accept `abs(std::complex<int>(5, 3))` returning either `5` or `6`. It's maybe a niche, but I've spent most of my career working with complex integers. For people like me, it's a great shame they are not supported.