# Sorting complex numbers by their argument

Tags: c++

I have a vector of complex numbers and I need to sort them by their argument. Sadly, the numbers have type `complex<int>`, so function `arg(c)` returns an integer in range [-3,3]  instead of a float and the numbers can't be sorted properly.

I've tried also

```cpp
typedef complex<int> ci;
typedef complex<double> cd;

vector<ci> a;
sort(a.begin(), a.end(), [](ci v, ci u) { return arg(cd(v)) < arg(cd(u)); });
```

but it does not work either (compilation error: `no matching function for call to ‘std::complex<double>::complex(ci&)`).
Can I sort these numbers without changing their type?

Comment: and the error is ? please post a [mcve] and the compiler error message

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I've edited the question.
and yes, I mean by the angle

Comment: btw type aliases are typically used to make the code more readable. `ci` and `cd` are rather cryptic

Comment: @ThomasWeller then we can say that they are equal to each other

Comment: i find it odd that `arg( complex<T>)` returns `T`. Though why don't you use `complex<double>` ?

Comment: I'd rather not use `complex<double>` because later on I need to sum up a lot of those numbers and I'm a little worried about floating point errors. Probably I even need `complex<long long>`, but it does not change anything in my problem with sorting.

Comment: `std::complex` does not even seem to be intended for use with anything other than floating point types. The standard says that instantiation with any other types has unspecified effects. You should reconsider whether to use `std::complex<int>` at all.

Comment: See also [Why does C++ mandate that complex only be instantiated for float, double, or long double?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11108743/why-does-c-mandate-that-complex-only-be-instantiated-for-float-double-or-lon.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the error because there is no converting constructor from `std::complex<int>` to `std::complex<double>` you have to construct the `std::complex<double>` by passing real and imaginary parts to the constructor:

```
#include <vector>
#include <complex>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {

    std::vector<std::complex<int>> a;
    std::sort(a.begin(), a.end(), [](const auto& v,const auto& u) {
        return std::arg(std::complex<double>(v.real(),v.imag())) < std::arg(std::complex<double>(u.real(),u.imag())); 
    });
}
```

Note that you can also use `atan2` directly without constructing the `std::complex<double>` as mentioned by user17732522.

Last but not least, reconsider if you really need `int` with `std::complex`. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex):

> T     -   the type of the real and imaginary components. The behavior is unspecified (and may fail to compile) if T is not float, double, or long double and undefined if T is not NumericType.

Basically this means that you need to check the implementation you are using whether it supports `std::complex<int>` at all.

Comment: You can also use `std::atan2` and skip the construction of `std::complex<double>`. (Just be careful, the arguments are the other way around.)

Comment: That is funny, default implementation of template has such conversion constructor, but specialization for floating points do not have it (conversion is limited only between floating point types). So conversion from `std::complex<double>` to `std::complex<int>` works. IMO should work other way around.

Comment: @MarekR As the answer now mentions, instantiating `std::complex<int>` at all already has unspecified behavior. I am not sure why the definition of the primary template definition with e.g. this converting constructor was left in the standard. Maybe this was just meant to allow implementations room to define the behavior of `std::complex<int>` and similar in whatever way they see fit?